# Selenium Keyword Driven Framework

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have developed the keyword driven framework and for each operations I have developed a function call like click, sendText. Now I have stored my test steps in sheets like, login in sheet1, logout in sheet2 and so on. After I run the script Pass or Error is written on the sheet for each step, so if excel has 5 sheets my write operation is done only at the last sheet. So where would be my mistake.

Comment: select your sheet before performing any action on it

Comment: Its performing all actions on the sheet but write operation is done only at last sheet

Comment: Add code to your answer